# onClick в custom TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, customview, android-on-click

В общем делаю custom view на базе TextView. Класс создаю таким образом

```
public class DayView extends TextView implements TextView.OnClickListener
```

и соответсвенно ниже обрабатываю метод `onClick`.
Свойство clickable пытался установить как в коде через `setClickable()`, так и через разметку `android:clickable="true"`, но почему то по клику обработчик не вызывается. Второй день уже бьюсь.

Comment: вопрос решил добавлением метода 'onClickListener(this)' при инициализации. затупил)

Comment: Я вас на 6с опередил)

Comment: стоило еще вчера вопрос задать) в итоге сразу же сам решение нашел) точнее свой косяк)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так... все работает

```
public class ExtTextView extends TextView implements View.OnClickListener {
    public ExtTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ExtTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ExtTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы определили обработчик кликов не означает, что он автоматически вызовется. Попробуйте его присвоить экземпляру вашего класса:

```
DayView dayView = ...;
dayView.setOnClickListener(dayView);
```

Либо прямо в кастомон классе:

```
setOnClickListener(this);
```